# Default Command not work

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

Hej i have some problem with my log in form.
In form i have 2 action:

```
<p:commandButton id="newUserButton" action="newUser" immediate="true" icon="ui->icon-plus" value="Zarejestruj się" />
<p:commandButton id="submitButton" action="confirmSignIn" update="logPanelGrid,messages" icon="ui-icon-check" value="Zaloguj się" />
```

and when i press enter on my keyboard i want to select automaticly second action "confirmSignIn"

When i hit enter application execute action "newUser"

i tryed use Default Command.

and i add some class:

```
package org.primefaces.examples.view;

public class DefaultCommandBean 
{  

    private String btn;

public DefaultCommandBean(String btn) {
        this.btn = btn;
    }

public String getBtn() {  
    return btn;  
}  

public void setBtn(String btn) {  
    this.btn = btn;  
}  

}
```

and i add some line to xhtml:

```
<p:defaultCommand target="#{defaultCommandBean.btn}" />
```

when i restart tomcat i get:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/WEB-INF/flows/main/welcome.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ""
```

can anyone knows where can be a problem ? i have no clue;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Your `action` attribute needs an EL expression. Instead of

```
<p:commandButton ... action="newUser" ... />
<p:commandButton ... action="confirmSignIn" ... />


<p:commandButton ... action="#{yourBean.newUser}" ... />
<p:commandButton ... action="#{yourBean.confirmSignIn}" ... />
```

whereas `yourBean` needs the methods `newUser` and `confirmSignIn`.

Secondly: Check the values of the String `btn` in `DefaultCommandBean`, are the values `newUserButton` and `submitButton`?

Comment: thx for answer i have fix it in other way. i change line witch i add to xhtml to:
    <p:defaultCommand target="submitButton" />
and its work fine :)

Comment: With the hardcoded target-string, you cannot change the `defaultCommand` in runtime. I thought that is what you want.

Comment: write now i just want to target 1 of 2 action. but thx for advice i will need it leter when my project growe up :)